# How does $(k+2)! + (k+1)(k+1)!- 1$ become $(k+2)! -1\,$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

While doing proof via induction I came across this:

$$(k+2)! + (k+1)(k+1)!- 1$$

It's supposed to simplify to $$(k+2)! -1$$
but I'm not sure how

We learnt how to simplify factorials when we divide them but not in multiplication, never-the-less, I thought about how $(k+1)(k+1)(k)! = (k+1)^2(k)!$ but this didn't lead me anywhere

Comment: There is an easy connection between $(k+2)!$ and $(k+1)!$: we have $(k+2)!=(k+2)(k+1)!$. Using this, you can factor out $(k+1)!$.

Comment: If $(k+2)! + (k+1)(k+1)!- 1=(k+2)! -1$ then $(k+1)(k+1)!=0$, obvious nonsense

Comment: As an aside... I strongly suspect what you *meant* to write was that $(k+\color{red}{1})!+(k+1)(k+1)!-1 = (k+2)!-1$.  The punchline is, as alluded to already, that $b+ab = (1+a)b$ by distributivity, here $b=(k+1)!$ and $a=(k+1)$ and noting that $(k+2)(k+1)!=(k+2)!$ per the definition of factorial.

Comment: This is not a [solution-verification] question. You have not provided any solution to be verified. Please do not mis-tag questions.

Answer (score 1):

It ain't be $(k+2)!-1$. You must have missed something.

$(k+2)!+(k+1)(k+1)!-1=(k+2)(k+1)!+(k+1)(k+1)!-1=(2k+3)(k+1)!-1$, because $n!=n\cdot(n-1)!$.